# Master Scheduling Batch Job Throwing errors Dynamics ax 2012 R2

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

When we are running the Master Scheduling batch job, its getting Ended but we are having below errors in the Log. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Error   Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)  Cannot edit a record in Planned order (ReqPO).
An update conflict occurred due to another user process deleting the record or changing one or more fields in the record.
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.LoadResourceWorkingTimesFromCalendar(Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Resource resource, Boolean forward, DateTime askStartTime, DateTime askEndTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.GetCapacitySlots(Resource resource, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Boolean forward, ICollection`1 capacityReservations)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.FetchCapacitySlots(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Boolean forward, Int32 capacitySlotsCount)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.Fetch(CapacitySlot unfetchedDataSlot, Boolean forward, DateTime enumerationStartTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveToNextSlot()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.AddAllSlotsFromSameDate(ICollection`1 currentDateSlots)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.UpdateAvailableSlots()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.ProcessCapacitySlots(JobResource jobResource, Resource resource, Boolean forwardDirection, Job job, Boolean calculateRuntime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobResourceBestTimeConstraint.Propagate(JobSchedulingEngine engine)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAllConstraints()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.WakeupAllJobContraintsAndPropagate(Sequence sequence)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAndSolve(Sequence sequence, OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleAttempt(OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch, Boolean scheduleIndividualSubSequences)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleSequence()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngineInteropExtended.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 _sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 _sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit) in WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.run.xpp:line 27
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrScheduler.Run() in WrkCtrScheduler.run.xpp:line 65
Error   Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    A CLR error occurred while invoking the scheduling engine.
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    An error occurred while scheduling order MO000246675
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.LoadResourceWorkingTimesFromCalendar(Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Resource resource, Boolean forward, DateTime askStartTime, DateTime askEndTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.GetCapacitySlots(Resource resource, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Boolean forward, ICollection`1 capacityReservations)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.FetchCapacitySlots(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Boolean forward, Int32 capacitySlotsCount)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.Fetch(CapacitySlot unfetchedDataSlot, Boolean forward, DateTime enumerationStartTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveToNextSlot()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.AddAllSlotsFromSameDate(ICollection`1 currentDateSlots)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.UpdateAvailableSlots()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.ProcessCapacitySlots(JobResource jobResource, Resource resource, Boolean forwardDirection, Job job, Boolean calculateRuntime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.Propagate(JobSchedulingEngine engine)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAllConstraints()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.WakeupAllJobContraintsAndPropagate(Sequence sequence)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAndSolve(Sequence sequence, OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleAttempt(OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch, Boolean scheduleIndividualSubSequences)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleSequence()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngineInteropExtended.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 _sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 _sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit) in WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.run.xpp:line 27
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrScheduler.Run() in WrkCtrScheduler.run.xpp:line 65
Error   Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    A CLR error occurred while invoking the scheduling engine.
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    An error occurred while scheduling order MO000246945
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.LoadResourceWorkingTimesFromCalendar(Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Resource resource, Boolean forward, DateTime askStartTime, DateTime askEndTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.GetCapacitySlots(Resource resource, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Boolean forward, ICollection`1 capacityReservations)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.FetchCapacitySlots(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Boolean forward, Int32 capacitySlotsCount)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.Fetch(CapacitySlot unfetchedDataSlot, Boolean forward, DateTime enumerationStartTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveToNextSlot()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.AddAllSlotsFromSameDate(ICollection`1 currentDateSlots)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.UpdateAvailableSlots()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.ProcessCapacitySlots(JobResource jobResource, Resource resource, Boolean forwardDirection, Job job, Boolean calculateRuntime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.Propagate(JobSchedulingEngine engine)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAllConstraints()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.WakeupAllJobContraintsAndPropagate(Sequence sequence)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAndSolve(Sequence sequence, OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleAttempt(OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch, Boolean scheduleIndividualSubSequences)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleSequence()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngineInteropExtended.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 _sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 _sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit) in WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.run.xpp:line 27
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrScheduler.Run() in WrkCtrScheduler.run.xpp:line 65
Error   Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    A CLR error occurred while invoking the scheduling engine.
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    An error occurred while scheduling order MO000246766
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.LoadResourceWorkingTimesFromCalendar(Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Resource resource, Boolean forward, DateTime askStartTime, DateTime askEndTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.GetCapacitySlots(Resource resource, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Boolean forward, ICollection`1 capacityReservations)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.FetchCapacitySlots(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Boolean forward, Int32 capacitySlotsCount)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.Fetch(CapacitySlot unfetchedDataSlot, Boolean forward, DateTime enumerationStartTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveToNextSlot()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.AddAllSlotsFromSameDate(ICollection`1 currentDateSlots)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.UpdateAvailableSlots()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.ProcessCapacitySlots(JobResource jobResource, Resource resource, Boolean forwardDirection, Job job, Boolean calculateRuntime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.Propagate(JobSchedulingEngine engine)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAllConstraints()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.WakeupAllJobContraintsAndPropagate(Sequence sequence)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAndSolve(Sequence sequence, OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleAttempt(OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch, Boolean scheduleIndividualSubSequences)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleSequence()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngineInteropExtended.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 _sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 _sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit) in WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.run.xpp:line 27
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrScheduler.Run() in WrkCtrScheduler.run.xpp:line 65
Error   Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    A CLR error occurred while invoking the scheduling engine.
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    An error occurred while scheduling order MO000247030
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.LoadResourceWorkingTimesFromCalendar(Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Resource resource, Boolean forward, DateTime askStartTime, DateTime askEndTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.GetCapacitySlots(Resource resource, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Boolean forward, ICollection`1 capacityReservations)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.FetchCapacitySlots(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Boolean forward, Int32 capacitySlotsCount)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.Fetch(CapacitySlot unfetchedDataSlot, Boolean forward, DateTime enumerationStartTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveToNextSlot()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.AddAllSlotsFromSameDate(ICollection`1 currentDateSlots)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.UpdateAvailableSlots()
   at 
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.AddAllSlotsFromSameDate(ICollection`1 currentDateSlots)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.UpdateAvailableSlots()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.ProcessCapacitySlots(JobResource jobResource, Resource resource, Boolean forwardDirection, Job job, Boolean calculateRuntime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.Propagate(JobSchedulingEngine engine)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAllConstraints()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.WakeupAllJobContraintsAndPropagate(Sequence sequence)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAndSolve(Sequence sequence, OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleAttempt(OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch, Boolean scheduleIndividualSubSequences)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleSequence()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngineInteropExtended.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 _sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 _sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit) in WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.run.xpp:line 27
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrScheduler.Run() in WrkCtrScheduler.run.xpp:line 65
Error   Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    A CLR error occurred while invoking the scheduling engine.
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    An error occurred while scheduling order MO000247462
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.LoadResourceWorkingTimesFromCalendar(Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Resource resource, Boolean forward, DateTime askStartTime, DateTime askEndTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.GetCapacitySlots(Resource resource, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Boolean forward, ICollection`1 capacityReservations)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.FetchCapacitySlots(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Boolean forward, Int32 capacitySlotsCount)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.Fetch(CapacitySlot unfetchedDataSlot, Boolean forward, DateTime enumerationStartTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveToNextSlot()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.AddAllSlotsFromSameDate(ICollection`1 currentDateSlots)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.UpdateAvailableSlots()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.ProcessCapacitySlots(JobResource jobResource, Resource resource, Boolean forwardDirection, Job job, Boolean calculateRuntime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.Propagate(JobSchedulingEngine engine)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAllConstraints()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.WakeupAllJobContraintsAndPropagate(Sequence sequence)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAndSolve(Sequence sequence, OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleAttempt(OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch, Boolean scheduleIndividualSubSequences)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleSequence()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngineInteropExtended.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 _sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 _sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit) in WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.run.xpp:line 27
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrScheduler.Run() in WrkCtrScheduler.run.xpp:line 65
Error   Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    A CLR error occurred while invoking the scheduling engine.
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    An error occurred while scheduling order MO000247401
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.LoadResourceWorkingTimesFromCalendar(Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Resource resource, Boolean forward, DateTime askStartTime, DateTime askEndTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.GetCapacitySlots(Resource resource, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Boolean forward, ICollection`1 capacityReservations)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.FetchCapacitySlots(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Boolean forward, Int32 capacitySlotsCount)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.Fetch(CapacitySlot unfetchedDataSlot, Boolean forward, DateTime enumerationStartTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveToNextSlot()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.AddAllSlotsFromSameDate(ICollection`1 currentDateSlots)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.UpdateAvailableSlots()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.ProcessCapacitySlots(JobResource jobResource, Resource resource, Boolean forwardDirection, Job job, Boolean calculateRuntime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.Propagate(JobSchedulingEngine engine)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAllConstraints()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.WakeupAllJobContraintsAndPropagate(Sequence sequence)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAndSolve(Sequence sequence, OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleAttempt(OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch, Boolean scheduleIndividualSubSequences)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleSequence()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngineInteropExtended.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 _sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 _sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit) in WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.run.xpp:line 27
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrScheduler.Run() in WrkCtrScheduler.run.xpp:line 65
Error   Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    A CLR error occurred while invoking the scheduling engine.
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    An error occurred while scheduling order MO000247403
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.LoadResourceWorkingTimesFromCalendar(Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Resource resource, Boolean forward, DateTime askStartTime, DateTime askEndTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.InteropEngineDataProvider.GetCapacitySlots(Resource resource, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Int32 neededCapacitySlotsCount, Boolean forward, ICollection`1 capacityReservations)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.FetchCapacitySlots(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, Boolean forward, Int32 capacitySlotsCount)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsCollection.Fetch(CapacitySlot unfetchedDataSlot, Boolean forward, DateTime enumerationStartTime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveToNextSlot()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.AddAllSlotsFromSameDate(ICollection`1 currentDateSlots)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.CapacitySlotsGroupEnumeratorBase.UpdateAvailableSlots()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.WorkingTimeAndCapacityConstraint.ProcessCapacitySlots(JobResource jobResource, Resource resource, Boolean forwardDirection, Job job, Boolean calculateRuntime)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobResourceBestTimeConstraint.Propagate(JobSchedulingEngine engine)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAllConstraints()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.WakeupAllJobContraintsAndPropagate(Sequence sequence)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.PropagateAndSolve(Sequence sequence, OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleAttempt(OptimalSolutionSearch optimalSolutionSearch, Boolean scheduleIndividualSubSequences)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.SequenceScheduler.ScheduleSequence()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Planning.JobScheduling.JobSchedulingEngineInteropExtended.Run(Int32 sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit)
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.Run(Int32 _sequenceScheduleRuntimeLimit, Int32 _sequenceOptimizationRuntimeLimit) in WrkCtrSchedulerJobSchedulingEngine.run.xpp:line 27
   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WrkCtrScheduler.Run() in WrkCtrScheduler.run.xpp:line 65
Error   Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    A CLR error occurred while invoking the scheduling engine.
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    An error occurred while scheduling order MO000247454
Info    Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling\Item number: 11-01-PU318\Operation 10 Primary  Production order MO000248020 could not be scheduled. Not enough capacity could be found
Info    Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling\Item number: 11-01-PU318\Operation 10 Primary  Production order MO000248021 could not be scheduled. Not enough capacity could be found
Info    Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling\Item number: 11-01-PU318\Operation 10 Primary  Production order MO000248020 could not be scheduled. Not enough capacity could be found
Info    Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling\Item number: 11-01-PU318\Operation 10 Primary  Production order MO000248021 could not be scheduled. Not enough capacity could be found
Info    Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling\Item number: 01-01-0010\Operation 10 Primary   Production order MO000247804 could not be scheduled. Not enough capacity could be found
Info    Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling\Item number: 01-04-0248\Operation 10 Primary   Production order MO000247933 could not be scheduled. Not enough capacity could be found
Info    Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling\Item number: 11-03-RD01\Operation 10 Primary   Production order MO000248270 could not be scheduled. Not enough capacity could be found
Info    Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling\Item number: 11-03-RD01\Operation 10 Primary   Production order MO000248270 could not be scheduled. Not enough capacity could be found
Warning Infolog for job Master scheduling (5637976151)\Infolog for task Master scheduling (5638710097)\Master scheduling    Item coverage is partly updated.

Comment: Did you take a look at [A CLR error occurred while invoking the scheduling engine](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeadaxsupport/2011/09/08/a-clr-error-occurred-while-invoking-the-scheduling-engine/)?

Comment: We did incremental cil, full cil, deleted xppil folders. We check the link you mentioned but no luck so far.. Nothing worked. It keeps getting this error.@FH-Inway

Comment: The error log mentions several orders where the scheduling failed (e.g. MO000246675). Did you take a look at those orders? Also do you have any customizations in this area? To be honest, it is difficult to give you any meaningful guidance on this issue. You need to analyze this issue on your system with someone who has a good knowledge of AX and master scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

Hi  have you tried to check in other entities if this issue occurs? Or checked the scheduling form if there’s an update or customised that developer did?

Comment: Hi facevidamo, nice having you here on StackOverflow! Just a tip: clarifying questions like yours are not an answer. Next time, please consider if it would be more suitable as a comment to the original question.

Comment: @facevidamo    There are no customizations for this. I checked it.